# I have problem sending automated emails with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, outlook, gmail, nodemailer

I am building node application , and i want to send email with "nodemailer" using outlook account, its work just fine for outlook and protonmail , but when i send email to gmail it get send but i dont receve it .
On my outlook inbox it is send but i dont have it on my gmail , and i looked spam as well.

The worst thing is that , if i send that not-automated mail to gmail, i still dont get it

I  am wondering if you guys had the same problem , and how you solved it ?
Thanks in advance , keep up the good work :)